# Cannot create a generic method: "T" not found

Tags: c#, generics, compiler-errors, ado.net

I am trying to implement a method that returns a generic list (List), but I keep getting this error message:

> The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

This is my method code:

```
public static List<T> doQuery(string query)
{
    SQLiteCommand com = new SQLiteCommand(query, SQLiteManager.connection);
    SQLiteDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.Default);
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        //other code
    }
}
```

Why is T not recognized as a generic Type in this situation?

Comment: `public static List<T> doQuery<T>(string query)` should do it. You must declare the generic types after the name of the class/method.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to tell what is "T" to the method, right now your method does not know what T is. T is known at compile time, the language does not figure out the type on the spot.

Here's an example: `static List<T> GetInitializedList<T>(T value, int count)`

Reference here: http://www.dotnetperls.com/generic-method

Comment: Just wanted to add the MSDN documentation on Generics, as it pertains to this question/answer. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx